# How to save published in Docker Container .NET project to host?

Tags: .net, docker

I need to publish self-contained .NET application in docker, and save it on my PC.
I tried to save it using -v parameter like `docker run --rm -v myHostFolderPath:/app/artifact myimage:latest`, but it doesn't work. I run container via /bin/sh. My published project exists! In artifact folder. But no files were saved on my PC after running container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["folder1/folder2/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
COPY ["folder3/folder4/MyLib.csproj", "MyLib/"]
WORKDIR "MyProject/MyProject.Api/"
CMD dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
CMD dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -o artifacts
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save"?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25292198/2501279) help?

Comment: @GuruStron , i published self-contained app in docker container. And i need to move it from container to my notebook :) p.s really, i need this to save app as artifact in gitlab ci/cd.

Comment: Maybe... Can you show me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [Custom build outputs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#output) for `docker build`:

```bash
docker build -o artifacts_path .
```

You will want to limit the output (as written in the docs `-o` will copy everything from the final stage). Add specific stage which will copy only needed files. Something along this lines:

```
# ...
# everything up to publish including it

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=publish /artifacts / # copy from publish artifacts to root

# rest of the file if any
```

If you have something after publish then use `--target` parameter for `docker build`:

```bash
docker build --target=export-stage -o artifacts_path .
```

Comment: artifacts_path - it is path on my pc?

Comment: @Murrchalkina yes, this is path where you want the results. The whole output of the final stage in multistage build will be put there.

Comment: error from receiver: failed to create dir \c\users\Мику\desktop\artifacts
Do you know what should i do?

Comment: @Murrchalkina I suggest to use some other folder not in the users directory - it usually requires specific permissions which docker should not have.

Comment: I tried to save it to c:/test, but 'directory name is invalid'

Comment: @Murrchalkina Cause it is invalid. Should not it be `C:\test`?

Comment: Just tried to do it this way. Still invalid... `docker build -o C:\test -t img -f Service/Dockerfile .` - i use it like that

Comment: Error: `error from receiver: failed to create dir C:\test\root\.local\share\NuGet....... The directory is invalid`

Comment: @Murrchalkina I think you might want to limit what you a trying to copy out. For my project I just created a specific stage which contained only needed data.

Comment: And... in that folder was created many "linux" folders, like home and other. But many of that - empty. And there is no "src" folder, which should be...

Comment: You wanna say, that I should use `--target` parameter in `docker run`? Or what?

Comment: @Murrchalkina you should not use `docker run` in the first place.  Please see the update

Comment: Oh sorry, i want to say in `docker build`

Comment: `mount3437207600/artifacts: no such file or directory`

Comment: @Murrchalkina this one you need to figure out yourself =) Possibly it should be `/app/build/artifacts` or `/src/artifacts` - in short you need to locate the artifacts in your container and use correct path.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. It's working. But it gave me `invalid directory name`. Ha-ha :) But i got files :D Is there any way to export just artifacts folder, without other `bin, boot, dev...` ?

Comment: @Murrchalkina was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one ;) As for exporting the artifact folder - yes, as I wrote previously you need to create a stage which will contain only it (as described in the previous update).

Comment: I've created it, but it exports me other folders too. And published app is corrupted :(

Comment: @Murrchalkina TBH for me only needed stuff was exported when correct target was used. As for app being corrupted - self-contained apps AFAIK are bound to the target platform and architecture - check out that you have specified a correct one.

Comment: I had a little mistake. Sorry =( Now its working correctly. Thanks a lot!!!