# Copy file from ephemeral docker container to host

Tags: python, docker

I want to copy a file generated by a docker container, and store inside it to my local host. What is a good way of doing that? The docker container is ephemeral (i.e. it runs for a very short time and then stops.)

I am working with the below mentioned scripts:

Python (`script.py`) which generates and saves a file titled `read.txt`.

```
with open('read.txt', 'w') as file:
    lst = ['Some\n',
             'random\n',
             'sentence\n']

    file.writelines("% s\n" % words for words in lst)
```

I use the below `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . /app/
RUN pip install --requirement /app/requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "/app/script.py.py"]
```

Below is my folder structure:

```
- local
    - folder1
        - script.py
        - requirements.txt
        - Dockerfile
    - folder2
```

Till now, I have managed to successfully build a docker container using:

```
docker build --no-cache -t test:v1 .
```

When I run this docker container inside `/local/folder1/` using the below command, I get the desired file, i.e. `read.txt` inside `/local/folder1/`

```
docker run -v /local/folder1/:/app/ test:v1
```

But, when I run `docker run -v /local/folder2/:/app/ test:v1` inside `/local/folder2/`, I do not see `read.txt` inside `/local/folder2/` and I get the below message.

```
python: can't open file '/app/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I want to be able to get `read.txt` inside `/local/folder2/` when I run the docker container `test:v1` inside `/local/folder2/`. How can I do it? I want to be able to do it without copying the contents of `/local/folder1/` inside `/local/folder2/`.

The docker container is ephemeral (i.e. it runs for a very short time and then stops.) Hence answers given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host/22050116#22050116)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292198/docker-how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-an-image-to-a-host/31316636#31316636) Stackoverflow posts, which focus on `docker cp` have not worked for me.

Time of running of the abovementioned container is not very essential. Even if a workable
solution increases the time of running of a container, that is okay.

Comment: Take a look at [scuba](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba), a tool I wrote for doing things with the current directory in a docker container.

Comment: Your host system probably has Python installed already.  Can you just run the second process as an ordinary subprocess, without involving Docker at all?  Do any of the recipes in [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the container is ephemeral, you may want to run the container and keep it running. And then copy the file.

Try the below steps:

**1. Keep the container running and run the python command.**

```
docker run -it --name temp test:v1 bash -c 'python script.py'
```

Here `temp` is the name of a temporary container.

**2. Copy file from temp container to local host.**

```
docker cp temp:/app/read.txt /local/folder2/.
```

**3. Remove the temporary container.**

```
docker rm temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: there's overlap between a mounted path and image's already existing filesystem, docker will choose to not override your host's (laptop etc) filesystem. So in `folder1` you were actually running the python code from your host's filesystem. To verify this you can change the `script.py` (add a new output line for file etc) and without building a new image, run the old one. You'll have different output.

### How to fix:

#### Simplest way

Just create another directory for output:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /output

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . /app/
RUN pip install --requirement /app/requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "/app/script.py"]
```

Change python script to write to `/output/read.txt`

```py
with open('/output/read.txt', 'w') as file:
    lst = ['Somee\n',
             'random\n',
             'sentence\n']

    file.writelines("% s\n" % words for words in lst)
```

Then mount output directory to `folder2`.

```bash
docker run -v /local/folder2/:/output/ test:v1
```

### More generic ways

You can choose output directory from environment variable and set via `ENV` in Dockerfile. Maybe use of `ARG` can be good use case for you.

### Disclaimer for *the obvious simplest way*

Usage of `/tmp` may cause problem that you never thought, some programs use sentinel files instead of IPC because you `/tmp` is mounted to host it'll override initial state of `/tmp` (I'm not sure it'll be ever problem but it may...)

Comment: My main aim is to get the file read.txt inside local host. That aim is not achieved with this solution.

Comment: I forgot to add volume binding command, edited the answer. (`docker run -v /local/folder2/:/output/ test:v1`)