# Download and extract files from Docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have the Docker image in Google Cloud, but the project with all scripts/files that were used to create the Docker image is lost and I can't restore it locally. Is it possible to load the Docker image from Google Cloud and restore the files? As far as I understand Docker Images contain the entire file system, but I'm unsure of the exact steps to access and extract all the files. How would that work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends heavily on the language and how the image was built.  If it's an interpreted language, and the image `COPY`ed the entire source tree in?  [Docker - how can I copy a file from an image to a host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292198/docker-how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-an-image-to-a-host)  A static compiled Go binary in a `scratch` image?  You can't get the original source back.

Comment: I don't know much about it unfortunately, so it was pushed with Dockerfile.txt and runinstructions.R, plus several R scripts. Is this the first or the second case?

Comment: @DavidMaze could you explain what you mean exactly? I am sorry, but I dont get it

Answer (score 1):

You can run the container and copy files by using 'docker cp' (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).
Copying files from the running container to the host: `docker cp container:/path/to/file /path/to/host`

Or just pull the image locally, inspect (`docker inspect <image>`) it and look for the '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/.../diff' folder. There you will find your files which have been copied via the COPY instruction in your Dockerfile.

Or you pull the image locally and save it as a tar with `docker save <image> > image.tar`. Then you extract it (e.g. `tar -xvf image.tar` ) and look for the image layer folders.
With 'docker inspect ' under .RootFS.Layers you get an overview of all layers. You need to find the right layer and cd into it and extract the layer.tar. Than you might find your files again.

Comment: I will try this at the weekend and come back here afterwards, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (not even sure what happened to my local files lol). Was able to retrieve the files without having to install docker locally by doing the below.

```
# go to artifact registry, locate the image
# click ... deploy to gce => spot machine
# in gce console contect to ssh
sudo find -name "yourfile.py"
# go to that path, for me /mnt/stateful_partition[...]/workspace
cd ..
sudo tar -czf workspace.tar.gz workspace
# only sudo has access to /mnt so copy
sudo cp /mnt/stateful_partition[...]/workspace.tar.gz /tmp/workspace.tar.gz
# check it exists and you have access
stat /tmp/workspace.tar.gz
# try: download file in the window, paste /tmp/workspace.tar.gz
# for me browser download didn't work but running this on my local machine did
gcloud compute scp <UserName>@<ServerName/InstanceName>:/tmp/workspace.tar.gz workspace.tar.gz --project {project name}
```

Then used [winmerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en) to compare directories.