# How to package files with docker image

Tags: docker

I have an application that requires some binaries on host machine for a docker based application to work. I can ship the image using docker registry but how do I ship those binaries to host machine? creating deb/rpm seems one option but that would be against the docker platform independent philosophy.

Comment: But a docker-based application should be autonomous in its container, no? If not, could you consider a wrapper to docker run, which makes a docker cp first? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22050116/6309)

Answer (score 1):

If you need them outside the docker image on the host machine what you can do is this.

Add them to your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) with [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) or [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Also had an installation script which calls `cp -f src dest`
Then bind mount an installation directory from the host to dest in the container.

Something like the following example:

e.g. Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY file1 /src
COPY file2 /src
COPY install /src
CMD install
```

Build it:

`docker build -t installer .`

install script:

```
#/bin/bash
cp -f /src /dist
```

Installation:

```
docker run -v /opt/bin:/dist
```

Will result in file1 & file2 ending up in /opt/bin on the host.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is based off of an image with a package manager, you could use the package manager to install the required binaries, e.g.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y required-package
```

Alternatively, you could download the statically linked binaries from the internet and extract them, e.g.

```
RUN curl -s -L https://example.com/some-bin.tar.gz | tar -C /opt -zx
```

If the binaries are created as part of the build process, you'd want to COPY them over

```
COPY build/target/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```