# Move file from Docker container to Host system in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, docker, docker-compose

I have configured Jenkins in Docker container. I am able to take a build. After a build I want to move WAR file into my Tomcat server which is running in host system. I have added copy command in post build task. Jenkins is not able to move the WAR to host system , since it is running in container.

How to move WAR file from container to Host system ?

Host path : /home/test/tomcat/webapps

Jenkins container path: /var/jenkins/workspace/dev/welcome/target/welcome.war

Comment: Are you running Jenkins in docker, or are you running a build job in docker? In case of the first, map any parent directory  of where you want to put the file on your host system into the container and copy it there (be careful with the user inside your container), so i.e `-v /home/test/tomcat/webapps/:/home/test/tomcat/webapps/` and then you can copy it as post build-step and it will persist (basically like the answer from @kimy82).
In case of the latter, your workspace will be mapped by Jenkins, so any files created during build will persist.

Comment: If you build something in a container, the `userid:groupid` will be the ones of the jenkins service user inside the container. So you must be able to alter this on the host system, or make sure they are the same on host and container (i.e if you user test has `uid:gid` `1001:1001` make sure your the user inside the container that creates the `welcome.jar` has the same `uid:gid` to prevent `Permission denied` on host

Comment: I am running Jenkins in Docker and taking build through that one. After build WAR is inside Jenkins container. Now I want to move the WAR to Host system. Which command I have to give in post build task script section. please help me on this.

Comment: when you spin up your docker instance with jenkins pass the option `-v /home/test/:/home/test`. This maps the home dir of test user to the exact same location inside the container (if user test exist in container choose different location, i.e `-v /home/test/tmp/:/tmp/`. Directory on host must exist, in container will be created automatically. Then in your post build step copy file there: `cp /var/jenkins/workspace/dev/welcome/target/welcome.war /home/test/tomcat/webapps`. The file should now be on your host at `/home/test/tomcat/webapps/welcome.jar`.

Comment: If you map a different directory (volume) you have to move it on the host system as well ofcourse

Comment: [Docker - copy file from container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22049212/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a volumne when starting jenkins with docker and then copy the war file there with a normal shell jenkins command. I usually do 
`docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/docker:/var/jenkins_home --net="host" --env JAVA_OPS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" --privileged=true axltxl/jenkins-dood`

The -v option is to create a volumne, which is a shared folder for container and host. In my case I use that for having the jenkins configuration outside docker container.

Comment: I have also done volume between container and host -v /home/test:/var/jenkins_home. how can I move the WAR to webapps folder after taking build. could you please give me solution for this one ?

Comment: You can create another volume  **-v {path to webapps}/welcome.war:/var/jenkins/workspace/dev/welcome/target/welcome.war** . That will hopefuly work. Not sure if it is possible to mount a volume of a file

Comment: I tried the same. But getting error while starting the container.

Comment: ERROR: for jenkins  Cannot start service jenkins: Cannot start container e9aa05b7724a8c2a001a225b75f9162b32a282c5abd3bd017ba0c40a76782d46: [8] System error: not a directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: @kimy82 you can map files, but only from host->client (file must exist on host)

Comment: It works for in my case, even if the directory doesn't exist in the container. I just have to make sure that the war is in the host ... if not it creates a directory. Do you have the last docker version?

Comment: If you have your DiD you can run in your Jenkins after war build **docker cp [containerid]:/var/jenkins/workspace/dev/welcome/target/welcome.war /home/test/tomcat/webapps/welcome.war** and it will work.

Comment: Moreover if you start your docker with a name  ex. **--name=jenkins** you can use the name instead of the containerId and there is no need to change jenkins shell command