# docker cp: Don't have permisson to create folder on host

Tags: docker

I want to copy a folder from docker container to my machine. I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copy-file-from-container-to-host).

So here is my command:

```
sudo docker cp 2f6aca7f2748:/root/scripts/ .
```

I got the following error:

```
mkdir /home/***/scripts: permission denied
```

I try `mkdir scripts`, and it is OK (of course). What could be the problem here?

---

### Update

Some more context: I'm using a NIS account, shared between both my desktop and server. However, docker is in the server, and I want to copy folder from host to my local folder on server.

Comment: did you try `sudo docker cp 2f6aca7f2748:/root/scripts .` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, I tried, and got the error above

Comment: I check and the issue is not coming on my machine. Something to do with permission on your directory on host? or a docker issue probably?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have no idea, I add some more details in my question.

Comment: Does the sudoers file have full sudo access for your NIS account?

Comment: Did you ever manage fix this? I have successfully run this command before on the same machine, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to @Fahri's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368015/7799568).

You need ownership for the destination folder,

Since I was about to wipe the machine anyways, I just set the ownership of the folder to any user with the following command.

```sh
sudo chmod -R a+rwX directory/
```

remember to not do this if you plan to keep the machine, refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101073/how-to-change-permissions-from-root-user-to-all-users) for proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description

it says :

> The cp command behaves like the Unix cp -a command in that directories
>   are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible.
>   Ownership is set to the user and primary group at the destination. For
>   example, files copied to a container are created with UID:GID of the
>   root user. **Files copied to the local machine are created with the
>   UID:GID of the user which invoked the docker cp command.**

Thats maybe the cause this problem.