# docker-compose volumes_from usage example

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can you please provide an example to sharing a path using `volumes_from` from container A to Container B, in addition how container B can access this path after sharing is done.

Thanks

Comment: What is your Docker version?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As documentation said [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) if you are in `version 3` you can use `The top-level volumes` to define a named volume as `db-data` ee code below and you can reference it in every services something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    nginx:alpine
    ports:
    - "80:80"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/db

  backup:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/backup/data

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

> version 2.0:

`volumes_from` allow you mount all data or volume from another service or container, you have to specify the access level how documentation said [volumes from](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) in your code you can use something like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - redis:rw
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - /data/webapp
  backup:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/backup/data

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /data/db
```

To code above `redis` define a volume services and then you can use in another container for example `web` with `volumes_from` look like web service use that volume service specify access level to `read and write`

Comment: How this can be done using docker-compose file `version 2`?
I guess it is using volumes_from syntax, can you please specify exact usage?

Comment: you can see it I updated with an example of version 2 docker.

Comment: Thank you, if you have several volumes defined within redis, is it possible to choose only one of them to be exposed to other services, using the `volumes_from`  syntax?

Comment: @JavaSa no, but you can always just copy and paste the original definitions you need.

Comment: Is it possible to reference a container brought up by a different docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @leggewie yes it's possible you have to declare it as an external volume in the root level of the docker-compose file and then access it as normal docker volume in the same docker-compose file and make sure the volume was created before.

Answer (score 3):

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    nginx:alpine
    ports:
    - "80:80"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/db

  backup:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/backup/data

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data

volumes:
  db-data:
    external: true
```

For me what solved was adding an external volume not created by compose using "external: true"
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external