# Set volume size for postgresql service in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following fragment of my yaml file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: dockerized_db
    build: ./DB
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - 5432:5432

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

How can I define size of my volume in docker-compose file for that volume used by db container?

Comment: The Volume size depends on the Host System(How much free disk you have). There is no size allocation for the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a volume with a size limit and attach it to the container, a good example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494746/docker-compose-volumes-from-usage-example)

The following example creates a tmpfs volume called foo with a size of 100 megabytes and uid of 1000.

```
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=tmpfs \
--opt device=tmpfs \
--opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
foo
```

[read more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)

Comment: A tmpfs mount might not be the best choice for the backing store for a database.

Comment: Sure, good point! 
But, my guessing that it's for DEV/QA environment.

Comment: The question is about `docker-compose.yml` though!

Answer (score 2):

The question is about `docker-compose`, so you are able to set Docker volumes size quota within docker-compose driver opts as the following way:

```
volumes: 
  tmpfs: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: "size=100m,uid=1000"
      device: tmpfs
      type: tmpfs
```

For details, please go to see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options