# How to share directory from one container to another one using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pocketbase

dockerized Node.js application that I've developed holds the `pb_migrations` directory. In below Docker Compose document you can see that it depends on dockerized version of PocketBase.

What I want to achieve is that the PB container upon start should have the `/app/pb_migrations` directory from `node` container available on its `/pb_migrations` path.

I have tried to use named volume to do so, but the directory is empty for PB container. I don't want to copy the directory separately every time and mount it from the host, and would love to just use the `docker-compose.yml` document to run it.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  pocketbase:
    image: spectado/pocketbase:0.19.2
    container_name: pocketbase
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8090:80'
    volumes:
      - pb_data:/pb_data
      - pb_migrations:/pb_migrations/
  app:
    image: app:latest
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - pb_migrations:/app/pb_migrations/
    ports:
      - '$PORT:$PORT'
    depends_on:
      - pocketbase
volumes:
  pb_data:
  pb_migrations:
```

Comment: Everything looks right. Make sure your services are configured to use those paths (/pb_migrations/ and /app/pb_migrations/). have you tried rebuilding without using cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Still, the Pocketbase container is missing the migration files in `pb_migrations/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

to make the `/app/pb_migrations` dir from the app container available at the `/pb_migrations` path in the `pocketbase` container using Docker Compose, you can use a bind mount. Bind mounts let you directly connect a directory from one place, like the host or another container, into another container.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

you can checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494746/docker-compose-volumes-from-usage-example)