# Export environment variables from docker to host

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running a docker container on Jenkins. I can't install anything on jenkins, so I did some processing on docker and want to get the results out to the host. If I set an environment variable in the docker container, how do I extract it to my jenkins host?

[I can see that I can write the env variable to a file and copy it to the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copy-file-from-container-to-host), but is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

When running the container, you can mount a file or a folder into the container. Inside your container, you can write to this file and have the changed reflected on the host file on the machine.

To do that create a file result.txt on the host machine and when running the container, specify the `-v` option to mount the file.

```
docker run -v ./result.txt:/result.txt ...
```

And let the jenkins job write the results into this file.