# Copy entire directory from container to host

Tags: docker, keycloak, docker-copy

I'm trying to copy an entire directory from my docker image to my local machine.

The image is a keycloak image, and I'd like to copy the themes folder so I can work on a custom theme.

I am running the following command -

```
docker cp 143v73628670f:keycloak/themes ~/Development/Code/Git/keycloak-recognition-login-branding
```

However I am getting the following response -

```
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file keycloak/themes in container 143v73628670f
```

When I connect to my container using -

```
 docker exec -t -i 143v73628670f /bin/bash
```

I can navigate to the themes by using -

```
cd keycloak/themes/
```

I can see it is located there and the files are as expected in the terminal.

I'm running the instance locally on a Mac.

How do I copy that entire themes folder to my local machine? What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: [Docker - copy file from container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22049212/6521116)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**EDIT**

As a result of running 'pwd' your should run the Docker cp command as follows:

```
docker cp 143v73628670f:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes ~/Development/Code/Git/keycloak-recognition-login-branding
```

You are forgetting the trailing ' / '. Therefore your command should look like this:

```
docker cp 143v73628670f:/keycloak/themes/ ~/Development/Code/Git/keycloak-recognition-login-branding
```

Also, you could make use of Docker volumes, which allows you to pass a local directory into the container when you *run* the container

Comment: hmmm, I am still getting "Error response from daemon: Could not find the file /keycloak/themes/ in container....."

Comment: oki go to keycloak/themes on your container and run pwd and post the output please

Comment: It returns "/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes"

Comment: @pgGriff I've edited my answer to match the output you've just pasted, hope it works now