# unable to understand docker cp command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image]

I am trying to copy file from docker container to host. I have attached the snapshot in which I listed all the containers as well as container file structure. But when I execute docker cp, it says it could not find the file. Can anyone tell me what wrong am I doing or if I am missing something. I am very new to docker so please guide me through.

Comment: When a container path is not absolute, it is assumed relative to the root `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to absolute path to the file inside the container. See the following.

[Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

```
docker cp <CONTAINER>:/<ABS_PATH>/procfile .
```

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description) for the docker cp command:

> The docker cp command assumes container paths are relative to the
>   container’s / (root) directory

Thus `CONTAINER:file.txt` is equivalent to `CONTAINER:/file.txt` as paths are interpreted relative to the root `/`