# How to share file from docker container to host

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker container which is running fine. It generates a few files in the directory `/Project/userfiles.txt`. I need these files for some testing purpose. But when this container is stopped everything is deleted. So I need to copy this file from the container to host.

I have a python application running in the container which is generating the file. I want some command or any way through which I can send the `userfiles.txt` to host at the end when the container is stopped.

To do this I can use `docker cp` command and I tried it but it gave me an error `docker not found` as docker is not installed.

**How can I share files from container to host?**

Comment: Where are you running `docker cp` ?

Comment: @vivekyad4v Sorry I forgot to mention, I was running docker cp in container as my code is running there and this command I mentioned inside code.

Comment: You can run it on the host itself. Any specific reason to run it inside the container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a **[volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)** (a bind mount one) to make sure the files written in /Project are persisted.

[image: volumes]

That means you need to docker run your image with a `-v /host/path:/Project` option.
See "[Use bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/)" for the simplest approach (which is to share a host folder with your container)

Comment: can you explain more. If I docker run with `-v /host/path:/Project`, so after the container is stopped I will get the `userfile.txt` in `/host/path`.?

Comment: Exactly, you will be able to access it there.

Answer (score 14):

Use `docker cp` on the host & not inside the container. In your case the command may look as below -

```
$ docker cp mycontainer:/Project/userfiles.txt userfiles.txt
```

After command completion you will get the file on host in the directory where you ran the `docker cp` command.

PS - I just checked that it works even if your container is in stopped state. For instance -

```
$ docker cp 9059e95cbe33:/etc/rc.local rc.local

9059e95cbe33 - Exited container ID/Name
```

Answer (score 3):

use following commands:

```
docker ps -a
```

Get NAMES at end of columns which you run with docker.

```
docker cp CONTAINER-NAMES:CONTAINER_DIR-to-copy PATH-to-Copy
```

Example:

```
docker cp <xxx_yyy>:/folder/path/in/Container/to/copy /home/user/path/to/copy
```