# Get data from container in a volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a Docker container within a Tomcat server. I would like to access to  the conf files of the server from the host.
In this way, i tried to run my container with these options :

`docker run -v /home/empty_dir:/usr/local/tomcat/conf test`

The /conf directory is well created on the host but is empty and thus the server cannot start...
So, I'm looking for a solution to populate my dir with the default conf file of the server in the container.

Comment: I also tried to create my dir /home/conf, but it seems to be the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Comment: `docker run -v` will always effectively "overwrite" image contents with host-filesystem contents in a new container (with a very specific exception this probably doesn't hit).  But you could use `docker cp` to copy the content out of the image, and then when you launch a new container you'll have a copy of the config tree to start from.

Comment: yes, it was my 'last' solution, but i found it dirty and though a way to do it more properly existed ^^ anyway thx for your help

Comment: i still have the problem but now with my logs, the files are not created in the shared volume. It's a problem because i would like to get these logs from another service to print them (and i cannot user `docker volume` because i need these logs in a specific dir on the host) ... any ideas ?