# Run command on jenkins docker container to copy file to host

Tags: docker, jenkins, copy, host, docker-container

Is there a way to copy file from docker container to the host by running the command on the container itself?
I know that I can use "volume" but it will not work - I want to copy files from container to arbitrary places on the host.
Only SCP file vis SSH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Answer (score 0):

From: [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host) you can run:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```