# how to copy file from docker container to host using shell script?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created an image, which is an automation project. when I run container it executes all test inside the container then it generates the test report. I want to take this report out before deleting container.

```
    FROM maven:3.6.0-ibmjava-8-alpine

COPY ./pom.xml .

ADD ./src $HOME/src

COPY ./test-execution.sh /

RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dassembly.skipAssembly=true

ENTRYPOINT ["/test-execution.sh"]

CMD []
```

Below is shell file

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo parameters you provided : "$@" 

mvn test "$@"

cp api-automation:target/*.zip /Users/abcd/Desktop/docker_report
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/  may help

Comment: Another way to solve this (instead of copying files out of the container) is to `--volume` mount a directory from your host into the container where the output is produced. It's not clear from your question where this would be, but something along the lines of `--volume=/host/path/output:/container/path/output`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `docker cp` command. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) for more details.

However, it appears `docker cp` [does not support](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7710) standard unix globbing patterns (i.e `*` in your src path).

So instead you will want to run:

`docker cp api-automation:target/ /Users/abcd/Desktop/docker_report`

However, then you will have to have a final step to remove all the non-zip files from your `docker_report` directory.