# Docker mount volume to reflect container files in host

Tags: docker

The use case is that I want to download and image that contains python code files. Assume the image does not have any text editor installed. So i want to mount a drive on host, so that files in the container show up in this host mount and i can use different editors installed on my host to update the code. Saving the changes are to be reflected in the image.

if i run the following >

```
docker run -v /host/empty/dir:/container/folder/with/code/files -it myimage
```

the */host/empty/dir* is still empty, and browsing the container dir also shows it as empty. What I want is the file contents of */container/folder/with/code/files* to show up in */host/empty/dir*

Comment: Can you get the original source code of the application, make your changes, make `pytest` pass, and then `docker build` a new image?  That'd be the more typical Docker path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sébastien Helbert answer is correct. But there is still a way to do this in 2 steps.

First run the container to extract the files:

```
docker run --rm -it myimage
```

In another terminal, type this command to copy what you want from the container.

```
docker cp <container_id>:/container/folder/with/code/files /host/empty/dir
```

Now stop the container. It will be deleted (--rm) when stopped.
Now if you run your original command, it will work as expected.

```
docker run -v /host/empty/dir:/container/folder/with/code/files -it myimage
```

There is another way to access the files from within the container without copying it but it's very cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian and Paulo. couple of extra steps, but simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/host/empty/dir` is always empty because the volume binding replaces (overrides) the container folder with your empty host folder. But you can not do the opposite, that is, you take a container folder to replace your host folder.

**However, there is a workaround** by manually copying the files from your container folder to your host folder. before using them as you have suggested.

For exemple :

1. run your docker image with a volume maaping between you host folder and a temp folder : `docker run -v /host/empty/dir:/some-temp-folder -it myimage`
2. copy your `/container/folder/with/code/files` content into `/some-temp-folder` to fill you host folder with you container folder
3. run you container with a volum mapping on `/host/empty/dir` but now this folder is no longer empty : `run -v /host/empty/dir:/container/folder/with/code/files -it myimage`

**Note that steps 1 & 2 may be replaced by** : [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host?rq=1)