# How to retrieve file from docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile which creates a zip file and I'm trying retrieve the zip file once it is ready. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essentials gcc

ENTRYPOINT ["zip","-r","-9"]
CMD ["/lib64.zip", "/lib64"]
```

After reading through the docs I fee like something like this should do it but I can't quite get it to work.

```
docker build -t ubuntu-libs .
docker run -d --name ubuntu-libs --mount source=$(pwd)/,target=/lib64.zip ubuntu-libs
```

One other side question: Is is possible to rename the zip file from the command line?

### Edit:

This is different than the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host) mentioned in the comments because while they're using `cp` to copy file from a running Docker container I'm trying to mount a directory upon instantiation.

Comment: you are mapping a directory of the host to a file in the container? try mounting directory to directory, and create the zip inside that directory, it should work (also, does 'apt-get install -y' do anything without a package name?)

Comment: @flagg Am I not mapping the root (/) with the current working directory (pwd)?  You're right that should be `apt-get install -y build-essentials gcc`

Comment: I'm not really experienced with the --mount command (I usually use --volume) but looking at the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-or-volumes I think you are missing the specification of 'type' (which should be 'bind') and the target should be a directory, but you are pointing it to a file (/lib64.zip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Comment: Note: Modified answer for a tested method using volumes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

## Using docker cp:

```
docker cp <container_hash>:/path/to/zip/file.zip /path/on/host/new_name.zip
```

---

## Using docker volumes:

As you were leading to in your question, you can also mount a path from the container to your host. You can either do this by specifying where on the host you want the mount point to be or don't specify where the mount point is and let docker choose. Both these paths require different approaches.

### Let docker choose host mount location

```
docker volume create random_volume_name
docker run -d --name ubuntu-libs -v random_volume_name:<path/to/mount/in/container> ubuntu-libs
```

The content will be located on your host, here:

```
ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes/random_volume_name/_data/
```

### Let me choose host mount location

```
docker run -d --name ubuntu-libs -v <existing/mount/point/on/host>:<path/to/mount/in/container> ubuntu-libs
```

This creates a clean/empty location that is shared as per the locations defined in the command. Now you need to modify your Dockerfile to copy the artifacts to this path, something like:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essentials gcc

ENTRYPOINT ["zip","-r","-9"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/lib64.zip", "/lib64", "cp", "path/to/zip/file.zip", "<path/to/mount/in/container>"]
```

The content will now be located on your host, here:

```
ls -l <existing/mount/point/on/host>
```

I got to give a shout out to @joaofnfernandes from [here](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/2979), who does a great job explaining.

Answer (score 2):

As @flagg19 commented, you should be binding a directory onto a directory. You can make up directories inside the container, and you can override the `RUN` arguments. Doing both plus adding `type=bind` leads to great success:

```
docker run -d --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/out ubuntu-libs /out/lib64.zip /lib64
```

Or of course you could change the Dockerfile `RUN` command to write to `/out/lib64.zip` instead of `/lib64.zip`:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essentials gcc && mkdir /out

ENTRYPOINT ["zip","-r","-9"]
CMD ["/out/lib64.zip", "/lib64"]
```

```
docker run -d --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/out ubuntu-libs
```

Either way, I recommend adding `--rm` and getting rid of `--name`. No need to keep around the container after it's done.

Comment: I get the following error: `docker: Error response from daemon: create [PATH TO PWD]: "[PATH TO PWD]" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Comment: hmmm, strange because the error does start with a /. `... create /Users/path/to/my/project: "/Users/path/to/my/project" ...`

Comment: @Pardoner add `type=bind`, right now you have no type and it defaults to `volume`, and `source` with `type=volume` wants a volume name (that's why it complains about invalid character, a path is not a valid volume name), try with: `docker run -d --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/out ubuntu-libs`