# Copy a file from docker container to host

Tags: docker

Is there any other way to copy a file or folder from `docker` container to host machine by running a command in the container?

All the other questions I read suggested running `docker cp` command on the host machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *May be also a duplication of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)*

You are right, that for copying files between container and host, you will always get the 2 options:

Option 1: **use `docker cp <containerid>:/<path> <host-path>`** ([more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/))

The reason you cannot run this command from the container is because of encapsulation ([containerization principle](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/containerization.html)). As such the dependency is uni-directional. *The host knows about the container, the container doesn't know about the host*. As an analogy, think of the real containers from a ship, once the container is closed you cannot move the cargo from container to the ship from within the container - unless somebody from the ship decides to open it (of course, unless your container wasn't compromised and they made a hole in the container shell)

Option 2: **use `docker` `volumes`** (recommended - [more](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/))

In this case, you `mount` the `<host-path>` in the container (during the execution `docker run` - or is part of your orchestration) and the command you run is: `cp <from> <to>`. The container doesn't even know is actually *a real path* on the host.

There is also the question of `why do you need to copy ?`. Knowing that any path in the container is already on the host, you may just find that file/folder path using `docker inspect <containerid>` and copy from the `/var/lib/docker/containers/<containerid>/<path>`. So, giving the whole context of what type of data you want to copy and for what reason, and in what environment (DEV/PROD) may give you other options.

Answer (score 1):

Asumming that your container id is abc123 you can do

```
docker cp abc123:/path/to/file /host/destination/folder
```

If you want to share folder between host an container, the best option are VOLUMES.

If you can't destroy the container you always can install ssh client and use scp.

Comment: I cannot run this from the container. I need a command i can run in the container.

Comment: Use VOLUME or SCP