# How to copy file from docker container of remote server to local machine

Tags: shell, docker, server, command, containers

How to copy file from docker container of remote server to local machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Answer (score 3):

***docker to remote server* Use:** `docker cp [Container Id]:/[absolute file location on container] [remote server location to save file]`

Ex: `docker cp d3e014rt404a:/usr/local/project/log.txt log.txt`

***remote server to local* Use:** scp `[user]@[remote_address]/[file_location] [local file location]`

Ex: `scp user@11.11.101.101:/home/user/log.txt log.txt`

Comment: `ssh` accepts a command a parameter, e.g. can: `ssh user@host "docker cp container:/path/to/file.txt /path/to/output/file.txt" && scp user@host:/path/to/output/file.txt .`