# Python Docker container says test coverage written to xml file but no xml file available

Tags: python, docker

I have a simple Docker container from `python:3.8.3`.

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir fastapi python-multipart httpx pytest requests pytest-cov

COPY app ./app
COPY tests ./tests
COPY pytest.ini ./pytest.ini

WORKDIR /
```

I then run the container to execute pytest and generate a coverage file.

```
docker run -it testimage python -m pytest tests -v --cov=app --cov-report xml:/coverage.xml
```

Doing this I get the tests to run fine and that the xml file has been generated.

```
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-2.10.0
collected 11 items
 ...
tests/test_main.py::test_invalid_missing_params PASSED                                                                                                                                                                           [100%]
----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.3-final-0 -----------
Coverage XML written to file /coverage.xml
```

So all appears fine. I can run this command inside the container and see that the coverage.xml is generated too.

But when I try to get that file copied out of the container to artifact the `coverage.xml`, or even just view the file to make sure it's there by appending `&& cat coverage.xml` to my run statement I always get: `cat: coverage.xml: No such file or directory`.

So I'm not sure what I've done wrong here

I did also try using docker `cp` and appending that to my run command.

`&& docker cp testimage:/coverage.xml ~/Development/coverage.xml`

but that too results in `Error: No such container:path: testimage:/coverage.xml`

Comment: have you tried the `docker cp` command? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host

Comment: @TinNguyen Good question, yes I also tried this. I should update my Q. But the same problem, because the file doesn't seem to exist, even though the output says it's written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing the `&& cat coverage.xml`, I think that is getting run after the docker command is complete, not in the container. So it's like `(docker run ...) && cat`

To run it in the container, you could do something like `docker run -it testimage sh -c 'python ... && cat /coverage.xml'`

But really what you want to do is copy the xml file out of the container. Your `docker cp` command is using the *image* name (testimage), rather than the *container* name. When you run the container, you can supply something like `--name mycontainer` and then use `&& docker cp mycontainer:/coverage.xml ~/Development/coverage.xml`

Keep in mind you will need to remove the container after each run if the name is the same.

Another option is to use a volume, so something like
`docker run -it -v ~/Development:/output testimage python -m pytest tests -v --cov=app --cov-report xml:/output/coverage.xml`

Comment: Yeah, that started to dawn on me after I posted that the docker container process had exited by the time I was trying to copy the file to the host machine. - Thanks