# Cannot copy files from source folder to Docker image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to copy the folder and contents from a source to a Docker container using an image. I built the image from my Dockerfile.

```
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash user1 && \
ln -s /foo /home/user1/foo

RUN mkdir /foo && && chown -R user1:user1 /foo
VOLUME /foo
```

After I build the Docker image, I run these commands to create a container.

```
docker run -it
--name container_name \
--mount "type=bind,source=$(pwd)/$FOLDER/container_foo,destination=/foo/" \
dockerimage:tag
```

The files from the source folder `/foo` isn't in the `/container_foo`. I checked by doing `docker exec -it container_ID /bin/bash` and confirmed that the files aren't there.

EDIT :

I just found out that `mount` only goes one way, exposing local host files/folder to the docker container. It doesn't copy the files inside of the docker container to the local folder when mounting. I removed creating the `/foo` directory from `RUN` and `VOLUME`. Instead I did this in the Dockerfile.

```
COPY --chown=user1:user1 foo/ foo/
```

And I was able to copy the files from source. Now I just need to copy it from there to `container_foo` when doing the `docker run ...` command.

Comment: what are you trying to do? do you want files from `container_foo` in docker under `/foo`?

Comment: Actually I want the other way around. I want the files from `/foo` to `container_foo`. I just discovered now that `mount` can't do that as it only goes one way, exposing local host files/folder to the docker container.

Comment: did you try `--volume`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)