# How to see the files running on my Google Cloud Platform Cloud Run service when using Artifact Repository?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-artifact-registry

This question
[How to see the files running on my Google Cloud Platform Cloud Run service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747819/how-to-see-the-files-running-on-my-google-cloud-platform-cloud-run-service)
seems to use `Container Registry (gcr.io files)`

How do I view the files in my image when using `Artifact Registry` as opposed to `Container Registry`?

I have run

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/bb-xyz/cloud-run-source-deploy/myservice:latest
```

but I get the message

> Unable to find image

Comment: Are you sure that docker is authorised to access artifact registry?

Comment: Have you tried this [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot) steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must authenticate your registry first.

As it says:

> Use these commands with the Docker client to pull the image. To use
> these commands, your Docker client must be configured to authenticate
> with $REGION-docker.pkg.dev. If this is the first time that you
> are pulling an image from $REGION-docker.pkg.dev with your
> Docker client, run the following command on the machine where Docker
> is installed.

```
gcloud auth configure-docker $REGION-docker.pkg.dev
```

After this, you can access it like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63748411/8382479).