# How to copy Docker logs to another directory

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile, docker-logs

I want to copy docker logs to another folder in the host machine. When we run docker logs  the output wants to store in a directory inside the host machine. Is there any solution for this?.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host

Comment: Can I change the path of the docker log file using the -v option? or how I make the change in the docker file to change the docker log path?