# docker cp throws "No such container:path" on running instance

Tags: docker

After trying `docker cp` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host/22050116#22050116), it still throws a `Error: No such container:path:...`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

- The container is running
- I can run `docker exec` commands
- `docker cp` fails

Comment: what is the host environment.. Linux?

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The `docker cp` command assumes container paths are relative to the container’s `/` (root) directory.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description*</sup>

This means that, when your `docker exec [CONTAINER] ls` is affected by the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir), your `docker cp` is not.

What you should do from there is to run:

1. `docker exec [CONTAINER] pwd`
2. Use what this yields you in the `docker cp` command to have a fully qualified path to use in you `docker cp` command

e.g. from the *httpd* image:

```
$ docker run -d --name httpd httpd

$ docker exec httpd pwd
/usr/local/apache2

$ docker exec httpd ls
bin
build
cgi-bin
conf
error
htdocs
icons
include
logs
modules

$ docker cp httpd:/usr/local/apache2/conf .
```

All this because [the *httpd* image defines a `WORKDIR`](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/077141ee37fca63972292c562ec0f632d0f831b1/2.4/Dockerfile#L10) on [the folder */usr/local/apache2*](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/077141ee37fca63972292c562ec0f632d0f831b1/2.4/Dockerfile#L6).

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you! I am quite a newbie to docker and documentation isn't all that clear to me yet :)

Comment: as another docker newb I was confused because docker-compose and docker have different names for containers. docker ps to find docker name