# Copy folder from Dockerfile to host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
################################
### INSTALL Ubuntu build tools and prerequisites
################################
# Install build base

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    subversion \
    sharutils \
    vim \
    asciidoc \
    binutils \ 
    bison \
    flex \
    texinfo \
    gawk \
    help2man \
    intltool \
    libelf-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libncurses5-dev \
    ncurses-term \
    libssl-dev \
    python2.7-dev \
    unzip \
    wget \
    rsync \
    gettext \
    xsltproc && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
ARG  FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1
RUN  git clone https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/openwrt.git
WORKDIR /openwrt
RUN ./scripts/feeds update -a && ./scripts/feeds install -a
COPY .config /openwrt/.config
RUN mkdir files
WORKDIR /files
RUN mkdir etc
WORKDIR /etc
RUN mkdir uci-defaults
WORKDIR /uci-defaults
COPY xx_custom /openwrt/files/etc/uci-defaults/xx_custom
WORKDIR /openwrt
RUN make -j 4
RUN ls /openwrt/bin/targets/ramips/mt76x8

WORKDIR /root
CMD ["bash"]
```

I want to copy all the files inside the folder mt76x8 to the host. I want to that inside the dockerfile so that when I run the docker file I should get the generated files in my host.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can simply use the volume mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the volume mount to access the docker-generated artifacts on the host machine.

you can also run the command

`docker cp` to copy the files to the host machine.

if don't want to use the docker command as mention only option is to use the volume.

you can also use `docker create` once the docker image is ready to create the writable layer and copy data.

Comment: Copying files from a docker *image* vs. a running container are different things. The solutions posted by others copy files from a container. To copy a directory from an image, you can use the `tar` command:


`docker run --rm  --entrypoint tar  MY_IMAGE_NAME czf - /path/to/mydir/inside/the/image > mydir.tar.gz`
and then `tar xzf mydir.tar.gz -C /host/path/to/mydir`

Comment: Thanks for sharing would suggested checking out Docker create once, without running actual container you can do same copy paste files

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

1. Use docker volumes to map the `/openwrt/bin/targets/ramips/mt76x8` folder when you are running the container. i.e. `docker run -v {VoluneName}:/openwrt/bin/targets/ramips/mt76x8`. All of the files in the `mt76x8` folder would be available in the volume folder. If you are using Linux then you will find the docker volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`
2. You can use `docker cp` command to copy data from container to the host machine. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)