# Installing PCL artifacts inside and outside docker container

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have build sucessfuly  from source https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl inside a docker container but i am not sure how to install PCL outside/inside docker container. My understanding is that inside docker container i just need to run `make -j2 install` eventhough i think i miss extra step regarding to root access. As for outside docker container, i was thinking of copying the files to host somehow and running install command from host. Is there a simpler way?

My PR can be found under https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/5107. Mainly refer to Installing PCL part.

Comment: Your docker container should have necessary tools pre-installed and then you can copy the folder from host to docker container and run your make command. Though, that's one way which I can think of.

Comment: Apparently i was refering the other way around. The files are inside docker container and i want them to be installled to host machine

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22049212