# Docker: biding an already existing container directory to a local directory

Tags: docker

I have a docker container (named 'clever_hugle') that already exists on my windows machine.

I want to bind my local directory c:\Users\me\Desktop\local_dir to the docker directory '\home\lat'.

From windows I do:

```
docker container ls
```

> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND   CREATED      STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
> f7c0a4258656   conda/miniconda3:latest   "bash"     2days ago    Up 7 minutes           clever_hugle

then

```
docker run --name=clever_hugle -d -v c:\Users\me\Desktop\local_dir:/home/lat -p 5000:80 clever_hugle
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to find image 'clever_hugle:latest' locally

I have already tried to find a solution for this, but I could not find anything.

Comment: Try to start it with container ID instead. docker run f7c0a4258656 arguments

Comment: @GeralexGR Thanks, I just tried, I get "Unable to find image 'f7c0a4258656:latest' locally"

Comment: @GeralexGR I think the problem is that "run" command can only be used to create a new container

Comment: Yes indeed. You should use run to create a new container. Your image is `conda/miniconda3:latest` as a result you should run docker run conda/miniconda3:latest arguments... In order to use your existing image, you should do `docker stop f7c0a4258656`. and then `docker start f7c0a4258656` arguments.

Comment: You mixed up the container name with the image name.

Comment: @GeralexGR The problem is that on the container 'clever_hugle' I already installed a bunch of things, so I really want to keep using it (and not recreate a new container)

Comment: @RandomFellow use the stop and start commands I gave you above

Comment: @GeralexGR just did it, then I did: **docker run conda/miniconda3:latest -d -v ./essai:/home/essai -p 5000:80 conda/miniconda3:latest** and I got this error: "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "-d": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown."

Comment: Try `docker run  --name yourname -d -v ./essai:/home/essai -p 5000:80 conda/miniconda3:latest`. Make sure the paths of -v are correct

Comment: yourname ? what is it suppose to be ? the container's name ?

Comment: indeed the name you want container to have

Comment: but then this new container will not have the content of this container f7c0a4258656

Comment: Your work is going to be lost; especially if you've installed things it's going to be hard to extract them from a container.  I'd suggest minimizing the amount of work you do in interactive shells in containers, and don't directly run base images like `conda/miniconda3`.  Instead, write a Dockerfile starting `FROM` that image that `RUN`s commands to install things, and check that into source control; that will produce a reusable image.  Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial has an overview of the process.

Comment: For individual files [Docker: Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host) might help you, but it won't know the history of things you've installed by hand or where they are.

Comment: Container = Base image (conda/miniconda3:latest) + some manual step
And you can’t reuse a container (clever_hugle) anyway. No workarounds. So what you can do if you have important files that you don’t to loose copy it from docker container (step mentioned just above). And in future create your own image (not container) using docker file. And whenever required just run the custom image.