# gitlab - trying to upload files from shared docker volume as artifacts

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-volume

I'm trying to upload files from a container as artifacts in my gitlab pipeline.  I'm trying to create a shared volume.  But I must be doing something wrong because I'm getting an error that there are no files to upload.

I have the following logic in my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  SHARED_PATH: testresults
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

deployDev:
  stage: deployDev
  environment:
    name: development
  script:
    - docker volume create ${SHARED_PATH}
    - docker build --platform linux/amd64 --target deployFunctionApp -t azuredeployserver .
    - docker run -v ${SHARED_PATH}:/builds/TestResults azuredeployserver
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ${SHARED_PATH}/test-results.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ${SHARED_PATH}/test-results.xml
  except:
    - main
  when: manual
  tags:
    - mac-pipelines
```

This is the error:

```
$ docker run -v ${SHARED_PATH}:/builds/TestResults azuredeployserver
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: testresults/test-results.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: testresults/test-results.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

**Manual Attempt**

after the image is built by the pipeline, i tried to do this manually from a commandline:

PS /Users/me/> docker run --rm -i -v=testresults:/build/testresults azuredeployserver ls -lah /build/testresults

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Apr 25 19:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Apr 26 12:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  809 Apr 25 19:42 test-results.xml

So I can see that the XML file is there - I just don't know how to get at it via gitlab-ci.yml

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1

I've modified the script to try the docker cp command:

```
  script:
    - docker volume create ${SHARED_PATH}
    - docker build --platform linux/amd64 --target deployFunctionApp -t azuredeployserver .
    - docker run --name $DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILD_TAG_ID -v ${SHARED_PATH}:/builds/TestResults azuredeployserver
    - docker cp $DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILD_TAG_ID:/builds/TestResults/*.xml ./TestResults/*.xml
```

But the error I see is

```
$ docker run --name $DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILD_TAG_ID -v ${SHARED_PATH}:/builds/TestResults azuredeployserver
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: .TestResults/test-results.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: .TestResults/test-results.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

For now going to see if I can hardcode the name of the image to test the docker cp command.  But if you see where I've gone astray, I'm all ears.
Also, I guess if I'm using docker cp i can get rid of everything related to creating a volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHARED_PATH=testresults docker volume create ${SHARED_PATH}` creates a docker volume named `testreults`.

When you reference `${SHARED_PATH}/test-results.xml` in the artifacts section, you are saying, "Look for `testresults/test-results.xml` in the GitLab Runner's local filesystem, which doesn't exist.

I think the most straightforward option here is to copy the file out of the container to a place where the GitLab Runner can access it.

[Docker: Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Comment: cool i had started down that path when you posted.  Please see edit 1