# How containerd copy a file from host to a running container?

Tags: docker, containers, mount, containerd

I find that I can use `ctr snapshot mount` to copy a file from a container to a host.
But how can I copy a file from a host to the container using containerd?
I used golang to write some code to start a container, but I can't find any documentation about copying host files to a running container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no provision as such with either with `ctr` or `crictl` cli to copy a host file to a running container as we have with `docker` cli (eg: docker cp).

Though there is a project under containerd known as `nerdctl` which is trying to emulate the same.

`nerdctl` is a Docker-compatible CLI for containerd.

Link for reference: [nerdctl cp command](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl#whale-nerdctl-cp)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
crictl exec CONTAINER-ID base64 /somewhere/filetocopy | base64 -d > filetocopy
```