# How do I view docker environment files?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, environment

I have a yml file that looks like this

```
version: '3.6'
networks:
  someplatform:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
services:
  loader:
    networks:
      - someplatform
    image: name/main:latest
    # docker-specific environment variables, such as service hostnames, go here.
    environment:
      - ENV_SECRETS=/src/path/to/local.secrets.yml
```

I want to look at the `ENV_SECRETS`, how do I do this?

Also I want to edit the file, but this image is running in kubernetes, how do make the changes and also ensure they are deployed in kubernetes?

I tried running

```
docker exec -it 64929986da3c cat /src/deployment/local/env/local.secrets.yml
```

I was expecting to see the yml file but got the message `"No such file or directory"`

Comment: Do you have any of the relevant source code beyond just the Compose YAML file?  When you say it's deployed in Kubernetes, is there perhaps something like a ComfigMap or a Secret object that has that file content?

Comment: Wwhat would be an example of something that would be useful? For now I just want to be able to look at the file in docker. What I know is that the source code has an environment file that tries fetching from ENV_SECRETS but I don't know how this process works 

I have something: 



```var environment: Environment = new ChainedEnvironment(Seq(
    FileBackedEnvironment(EnvironmentVariables.get(ENV_SECRETS)),
    ...
    ...
  ))```


And call it like this 

```Environment.get("api.some.path")```

Comment: Perhaps you want to be [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)?  The environment variable itself is "just" a string.  How content gets into the container is a function of the image's Dockerfile and anything that gets mounted into the container, in your case in a Kubernetes Pod spec.